# How to neatly combine multiple conditional statements

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I'm trying to add a sidebar widget to two different places. My code is working but there is duplication, so my question is how do I combine those statements?

```
            if( tribe_is_month() && !is_tax() ){ // Month View Page
                dynamic_sidebar( 'lavida_calendar' ); 
            } 
            elseif ( tribe_is_past() || tribe_is_upcoming() && ! is_tax() ) { // List View Page
                dynamic_sidebar( 'lavida_calendar' ); 
            }
            else {
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Just set both conditions in one statement with OR condition

```
if( (tribe_is_month() && !is_tax())  || 
    (tribe_is_past() || tribe_is_upcoming() && ! is_tax() )){
    dynamic_sidebar( 'lavida_calendar' ); 
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks Jaydp :) I'm sure I tried that but I think the multiple ||'s got me confused

Answer (score 2):

Since `!is_tax` exists in both branches, you can lead with that. Then, note all that remain are OR conditions:

```
if (!is_tax() && (tribe_is_month() || tribe_is_past() || tribe_is_upcoming())) {
    dynamic_sidebar(...);
}
```

This rewrite has the side effect of calling `is_tax` only once, though.

Comment: Thanks Bishop, that is indeed very neat and concise :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, it seens that this rule can be simplyfied, since it seens you want to show the sidebar for any month, past and upcoming which is not a tax

```
if ((tribe_is_month() || (tribe_is_past() || tribe_is_upcoming())
    && !is_tax()) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'lavida_calendar' ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jhonatan, i see your login there